# Mathematica function into R

Tags: interoperability

I am R user and very new to mathematica. I want to make run a .wl file into R script and using its results into the same R script. Is there any possible way to load and run .wl file into R?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: like that: [wolframscript](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html)?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any links between R and Mathematica that allow evaluating Mathematica code directly from within R.

The reverse, i.e. evaluating R code from within Mathematica, and using its result, is possible using [RLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html).

What you can do is call the command line version of Mathematica as a separate process from R, the same way you would [run a Mathematica script from a terminal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html), then parse its output as a string.  How to best do this in R is a question for an R forum.

To make parsing the output easier, you should encode it into a format that R can read directly. What formats can be used depends also on the nature of the output, but for simple numerical tables [CSV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) may be useful, and for more complex structures look at [JSON](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html).