# How to call a mathematica script from a Matlab script?

Tags: matlab

I need to call a Mathematica script from within a Matlab script and I wonder what is the best way to do so. I've heard about the Mathlink, but no idea how straight forward it is to work with it. I'd be so grateful for any guide and help.

Regards,
Marilla.

Comment: Since it is Mathematica site it would be nice to add what can you do in Matlab that opens the door for mma.

Comment: see analogous question about R: [153826](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153826/5478)

Comment: Ok, thank you; I'll post it there as well.